# Python, Pandas package issue

Tags: python, pandas, pip, package

I have been having issues with my pandas package after I tried to upgrade it. I decided to uninstall it using (pip uninstall pandas) but then after I tried to reinstall it (pip install pandas) it said that I already had all the requirements. Then when I try to run a script that imports pandas, I get an error saying no module named pandas.

how can i fix this?

Comment: curl --silent --show-error --retry 5 https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
pip install pandas

Comment: Pretty hard to say without having access to your system. Do you have any virtual environments installed?

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 and python 2.7, no virtual environments though

Comment: this might not make any sense but i did the following : uninstall pandas, reinstall it, uninstall it again , uninstall it again, then reinstall it and now it works

Comment: sometimes it is simply because you need to close the command prompt and reopen it to import newly installed packages.